# How to Connect Delegate method to HomeVC from Root VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates

I having a View Architecture like the figure.
From the RootVC, set the side menu and HomeVC.
I having a Delegate method in Side menu ,set the side menu delegate from RootVC itself, it is working fine.
I want to trigger the delegate method in HomeVC when the action done from the SideMenuViewcontroller. How can I connect sideMenu Delegate to Home viewController .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1) You have Home VC instance and SideMenu instance in Root VC. So you can assign the Side Menu delegate as Home VC. (I won't prefer it)

2) Follow the architecture, Pass the data from Side Menu to Root VC. Then Root VC to Home.

Side Menu <--> Root VC <--> Home VC

Answer (score 0):

**Notification design pattern** is not worth it for this:

You have to register notification from `HomeViewController` same like below,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_handleWhateverChange) name:@"whateverChange" object:nil];
```

And

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"whateverChange" object:nil];
```

Here you have to fire it from `SideMenuController`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering what library you are using, some of them provide very convenient way to get each controller from another, then you can do whatever you want to do

e.g. https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController

Comment: I having not only a side menu but also a tabs are there like a tabbar. For switching the tab I have used ContainerView.